# Invite a user to chat

Tags: support

Before marking as duplicate, please read.

I've set up a chat room, and I cannot find the link/button or whatever to invite a specific user to join.  A search of meta, and the help system suggests this is possible.  Instructions say variously, "from the chat room itself", or "from the info link".  I cannot find the buttons to push.

Can someone please be explicit about what the procedure is, and where on the screen the links/buttons/whatever are.

(FWIW [not much] this is yet another instance of me not being able to easily find instructions on using SE features.  I don't know what to do about that...)

Comment: Hm... as a temporary measure, you can copy the URL of the chat room and paste it into a comment which the user you'd like to invite will see. On your last point: if it's unclear how to invite a user to chat (which it may well be), it'd be useful to raise this issue on [meta.SE].

Comment: @DavidZ I have the same problem. The *temporary measure* was 2.75 years ago. Has a feature been added since then? I have not seen any.

Comment: @sammygerbil Not that I know of

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter the chatroom of your choice.
2. Look up the [Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users) profile of the user you wish to invite.
3. The chat profile gives you the option of inviting this user to join you in the room you are currently in, or to start a new chatroom with this user.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Now if you can figure out how to get the search feature  to find the posts that I *know* I've seen (or written myself!) I'll buy you a beer.  Two beers.

Comment: [Your own chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/111792/garyp?tab=general) lists your posts in chatrooms under "recent" (top right corner). If you recall some distinctive words used in your post, you can search for it from your profile using "search for messages containing" (orange toolbar in the main box).

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing as chat profile.  But the "search for messages containing" doesn't seem to find terms in *answers*.   I guess (but haven't checked) that it searches in *chat*.  Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @garyp To search for main-site posts you've written yourself, use `user:me` in the search box. As to main-site posts that you've *seen*, I strongly suspect SE's view tracking does not contain the required data to make it possible. It should be possible in principle to enable search over posts you've interacted with (voted / commented / etc) but I don't think it exists and I don't think SE is about to code that up.