# How can I start a conversation with a specific user (in chat or otherwise)?

Tags: support, chat, users

Say I provided an answer to a question, and then another user commented on my answer pointing out some mistakes. I realise my answer has serious flaws and decided to delete it.

Now, I want to talk to that user. To follow up the discussion started in the comments. I can start a chat room, but now there is no post / comment thread where I can post the link of the chat room. I cannot find this user in any other active chat room.

How can I "ping" a specific user, with no previous chat presence? Are there alternatives to chat?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about chat specifically, right? If so I'd suggest clarifying the title and/or tags of your question to make that explicit.

Comment: @DavidZ well are there other ways other than chat?

Comment: Assuming they have a chat profile at all, you can invite them to a chat room as described in [this previous meta answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9827/106502).

Comment: @Chris That would probably make a good answer

Comment: @Chris what if they don't have enough reputation to participate in chat yet, and/or they don't have a chat profile.

Comment: @SuperCiocia That's why I didn't post it as an answer, as I don't know if there's any way to contact them in that case. If you have trouble finding the user's chat profile, I suppose you could ask a moderator. Looking through your recently deleted answers, the user I guess you're talking about has a chat profile [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/218347/thomas).

Comment: @Chris Thanks for that! Then I did something wrong. Where can I go and type some username to see if they have a chat profile?

Comment: And on a separate note, do all users need a minimum reputation to even participate in other people's chat rooms? I am having that issue as well at the moment.

Comment: @SuperCiocia You can search [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users), but it can be tedious when they have a generic name, since chat is network-wide.

Comment: @Chris so how did you find him?

Comment: @SuperCiocia I *think* you can specify a user in the room settings to allow them to chat even if they do not have enough reputation.

Comment: @SuperCiocia Well, in this case they are on the first page of results if you search by "recent." But also moderators have a tool for that.

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately, chat room owners cannot allow low rep members to chat. Some of us have been asking for this for several years. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257949/4014959